# Exception when running a Jar on another computer (other Java version)

Tags: java

Playing with a little network program, created a Jar with netbeans. Runs just fine on my computer java 1.7.0.60, but when I take it to another computer that has a newer version of java 1.7.0_65 it will not run, I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>java -jar ReverseEchoServer.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: reverseechose
rver/SocketClient : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have read several posts on here that talk about PATH, have looked at that but no luck. I belive its the version differance. Any advice would be most appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: [Class file version 52 seems to be Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file). Sure you're running it with Java 7 on your machine?

Comment: AFAIK it will only make a difference if you will compile it in java 7 and try to run it in java 6

Comment: @M.Sharma no, it would be the other way round. Older class file versions would be executed (e.g. Java 7 can run classes compiled for Java 6 and below) but newer versions are simply reported as unsupported.

Comment: @Thomas OOPS mistyped

Comment: So would I update the JDK on the compiling computer to make the Jar work with the newer java?

Comment: I think you're confused about the version somewhere, probably on your own system.  (Remember, it's possible to have several different Java versions installed on a box, so doing `java -version` from the command line won't always tell you what's being used by Eclipse, et al.)

Comment: In any event, you probably need to specify the target version when you run *javac*.

Comment: Is there not a way to make it work with all versions?

Comment: To make it work with all versions, you specify a javac "target" version that is the lowest of "all" versions.  Something compiled for version X is always compatible with the JVM for version X+n.

Answer (score 1):

Java class files compiled for Java 7 have Major/Minor versions 51/0. If you have a JVM implementation that wasn't prepared for Java 7, it would give you this error indicating "I don't know how to interpret and run this class file."

Try either compiling for an older JVM version, or upgrade your JVM.

Use the Target and specify the version in which it needs to be executed using target switch followed by version number.

```
javac -target 1.7 yourJarName.jar
```